# How does a program recognize the difference between frequency and frequencies as variable names?

Tags: ruby, variables

```
puts "Get Text: "
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split

frequencies = Hash.new{0}

words.each{|word| frequencies[word] += 1}

frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|a,b| b}
frequencies.reverse!

frequencies.each do |word,frequency| 
    puts word + " " + **frequency**.to_s
end
```

Comment: you probably want to indent your code 4 spaces so it's formatted as code

Comment: you'll also want to separately declare the frequency variable.  I'm not sure what that value is.

Comment: They have different names :/

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't notice the initialized frequency variable earlier. Sorry about that. I feel really embarrassed. Thank you though.

Comment: as @Paul.s said, it's a different name.  Replace `frequencies` with `foo` and `frequency` with `bar`. It's just a variable name, since the _variables are named differently_, they are _different variables_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually worth answering from a newbie perspective, but only if we look at it from Ruby and Rails. A newcomer might get confused by the fact that in Ruby `frequency` and `frequencies` are two completely different variables. BUT in Rails, a newcomer is taught that Rails automatically pluralizes and singularizes for us in many instances. We create a tables

```
class Frequency < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :radio

end

class Radio < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :frequencies

end
```

You can then do things like:

```
$> r = Radio.first
$> r.frequencies

    Frequency Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "frequencies".* FROM "frequencies" WHERE  
"frequencies"."radio_id" = 1
```

Pluralization in Rails is a nice feature that can confuse a new user who is also new to Ruby. The same can be said for [Hash with Indifferent Access](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), I know that one confused me at first.